# What command does the same thing as enabling "expo" in CCSM Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, ccsm

I'm not able to find the right command to execute the 'expo key' in Compiz Config Settings Manager.

[image: Image of ccsm running]

[image: Image of what expo mode is.]

Is there a command to do the same thing as this setting?

Comment: What is "expo mode"?

Comment: Enter a terminal, type ‘# apt install compiz*’, then ‘$ ccsm’. In the search bar, tap ‘Expo’, you’ll find what it is.

Comment: When you seek help you really should provide as much information as possible - in the question itself. I was not asking out of mere curiosity.

Comment: Compiz Config Settings Manager is what your image shows. Compiz is a window manager, and CCSM is a tool to configure it. That's why your question was so confusing to us. Although I still don't know how to answer it, maybe someone who uses CCSM can...

Comment: I don't think there is a command per se. You could install xdotool & run `xdotool key super+s`

Comment: I misunderstood you. So - no, there is no longer a command to enable a specific plugin. (- there may have been before dconf/gsettings..

Comment: Technically you could use `dconf write` command but it would be unwieldy & you'd need to include all desired active plugins, hardly worth the effort to explain or do.

Answer (score 0):

The default shortcut for 16.04 is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, which doug mentioned at the comment can be run via `xdotool`, too. Install the package before proceed.

You might have not been enabled the workspace switcher. Install `unity-tweak-tool` package and run it either via Dash or terminal. Then, look at the Workspace Settings, turn on Workspace Switcher.

[image: Switcher]

Try hitting <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or simply click the switcher at the left of your screen. It should looks like this:

[image: Preview]

Now what did we need is a command. Create a `.sh` file (you can name it as anything) with the simple command:

```
xdotool key super+s
```

Do `chmod +x` to the file, and apply it to your desired place.

Comment: Yes I knew this. All what I want is a command which toggle the ‘expo mode’, like your ‘Super S’ shortcut.

Comment: @geremi doug's comment might be the answer. I have edited my post.